# How to tagger setInterval time value dynamically in for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm making a function that loops over multiple `img` tags to change the `src`. The loop is to fire continuously to repeat the images changing. The function works fine with the image sources changing as expected. The issue I have is that I want the change for each group of images to be staggered, for example:

1. First group changes after 5000ms
2. The second group fires after 6000ms
3. The third group fires after 7000ms
4. etc ...

```js
const ticker = document.querySelectorAll('.client-list');

  if (!ticker) return false;

  for (let i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {

    const el = ticker[i].querySelectorAll('.client-list__logo');

    for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {

      // Apply classes on page load
      el[0].classList.add('img-show');

      const intervalLength = 5000;

      setInterval(showImage, intervalLength); // TODO: this value needs to increase by 1000 for each iteration

      function showImage() {
        if (el[i].classList.contains('img-show')) {
          el[i].classList.remove('img-show');
        } else {
          el[i].classList.add('img-show');
        }
      }

    }
```

```html
<section class="clients">

  <div class="clients__header">
    <div class="prefix"><?php echo $clients['heading_prefix']; ?></div>
    <h2><?php echo $clients['heading']; ?></h2>
  </div>

  <div class="container-slim">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid-md-6">

        <?php 
        $output_1 = array_slice( $clients['column_1']['clients_repeater'], 0, 2, true ); 
        $output_2 = array_slice( $clients['column_1']['clients_repeater'], 2, 2, true ); 
        $output_3 = array_slice( $clients['column_1']['clients_repeater'], 4, 2, true ); 

        $output_4 = array_slice( $clients['column_2']['clients_repeater'], 0, 2, true ); 
        $output_5 = array_slice( $clients['column_2']['clients_repeater'], 2, 2, true ); 
        $output_6 = array_slice( $clients['column_2']['clients_repeater'], 4, 2, true ); 

        ?>

        
        <?php if ($clients['column_1']['clients_repeater']): ?>
          <div class="client-list-wrapper">
            <div class="client-list">
            <?php foreach( $output_1 as $client ): ?>
              <div class="client-list__logo">
                <img src="<?php echo $client['logo']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $client['logo']['alt']; ?>" />      
              </div>  
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div><!-- client-list : END -->

            <div class="client-list">
            <?php foreach( $output_2 as $client ): ?>
              <div class="client-list__logo">
                <img src="<?php echo $client['logo']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $client['logo']['alt']; ?>" />      
              </div>  
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div><!-- client-list : END -->

            <div class="client-list">
            <?php foreach( $output_3 as $client ): ?>
              <div class="client-list__logo">
                <img src="<?php echo $client['logo']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $client['logo']['alt']; ?>" />      
              </div>  
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div><!-- client-list : END -->
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        

        <?php if ($clients['column_1']['content']): ?>
        <div class="clients__column">
          <p><?php echo $clients['column_1']['content']; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

      </div>
      <div class="grid-md-6">

        <?php if ($clients['column_2']['clients_repeater']): ?>
          <div class="client-list-wrapper">
            <div class="client-list">
            <?php foreach( $output_4 as $client ): ?>
              <div class="client-list__logo">
                <img src="<?php echo $client['logo']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $client['logo']['alt']; ?>" />      
              </div>  
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div><!-- client-list : END -->

            <div class="client-list">
            <?php foreach( $output_5 as $client ): ?>
              <div class="client-list__logo">
                <img src="<?php echo $client['logo']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $client['logo']['alt']; ?>" />      
              </div>  
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div><!-- client-list : END -->

            <div class="client-list">
            <?php foreach( $output_6 as $client ): ?>
              <div class="client-list__logo">
                <img src="<?php echo $client['logo']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $client['logo']['alt']; ?>" />      
              </div>  
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div><!-- client-list : END -->
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($clients['column_2']['content']): ?>
        <div class="clients__column">
          <p><?php echo $clients['column_2']['content']; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I can't work out how to stagger the increase of the time value for each iteration. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be a great help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your snippet produces a syntax error...

Answer (score 1):

You have two nested loops, each controlled by a variable named 'i'. If each "group" is considered to be an iteration of the outer loop, you'll want to rename the inner loop control variable so the outer `i' is accessible in the inner loop:

```
const ticker = document.querySelectorAll('.client-list');

if (!ticker) return false;

for (let i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {

  const el = ticker[i].querySelectorAll('.client-list__logo');

  for (let j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {

    // Apply classes on page load
    el[0].classList.add('img-show');

    const intervalLength = 5000 + ( 1000 * i ); // 5000, 6000, 7000, etc.

    setInterval(showImage, intervalLength); // TODO: this value needs to increase by 1000 for each iteration

    function showImage() {
      if (el[j].classList.contains('img-show')) {
        el[j].classList.remove('img-show');
      } else {
        el[j].classList.add('img-show');
      }
    } // showImage()
  } // for j
} // for i
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1000 ms multiplied with the value of `i` in the loop:

`setInterval(showImage, intervalLength + 1000 * i);`